# Disable all Edit hoverables

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

As admin, Drupal has a ton of little hoverable 'edit' links.

Is there an easy way to turn them **all** off?

I know I can kill the Views version in admin/build/views/tools.  But there's still Block, Menu, Panels, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal core has no such feature. This comes either with a special module, or with the theme. Themes built on Zen have this feature, as well as many admin-themes.

If the latter, look for configuration options in your theme, hack the theme or choose another one, depending on your preferred way of managing your project. 
If the first, simply disable that module.

Comment: cool, I didn't realize much of this was coming from Zen.  I was able to turn them off there.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide them very easily with css, as it's just a few classes you have to target. Drupal 7 handles this issue, but I don't believe there is an easy way to turn them all off.

Answer (score 0):

Admin => Site building => Views => Tools =>  Do not show hover links over views (checkbox)